# Is there any danger of speedly repeating an ajax procedure?

Tags: javascript

```
$('#gd').on('click', function(){
    // move up and down DOM elements
    // some ajax procedure to store new values on database (php/mysql)
});
```

Is there any danger to repeating this click very quickly for a long time?

For example - if the connection is poor - will the ajax will not complete each time?

I tested on my live server - seems there is no problem, but... I'm still concerned.

And what is the way to avoid possible problems it this scenario - i.e. if a user keeps clicking very quickly on the `#gd` button.

Comment: Add a spinner overlay or disable `#gd` until the previous ajax is done.

Comment: If you want to ensure that always only one request is pending, you should implement a boolean variable like `isPending`, which you set to true after clicking and to false in the success- and error-handler of the Ajax-implementation. Inside the click event handler you then check for `!isPending`.

Comment: It will keep sending information to the Server. You should do as much code on the Client first to prevent that kind of thing. So, only send AJAX to the Server when you have done DOM testing. Then test again on the Server. If it doesn't pass the Server tests you have a malicious user on your hands. I like to redirect them to ic3. Also, if AJAX submission happens and all is good and nothing on the DOM changes don't send again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "Danger" would be more accurately described as undesired behavior. However, it is indeed issue which should be treated - as sending multiple request when only 1 is required would consume resources on both client and server with no reason.

If you would like to prevent the user from clicking the button while the request is being processed, disable the button after the client send it it, and re-enable it after response processing complete:

```
$('#gd').on('click', function(){
  // 1. do some stuff with DOM
  // 2. disable button + make ajax call
  $.ajax({someRequestOptions})
   .always(function() {
       // 3. re-enable button
   });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to re-enable the button also when an error occurs: use `always` instead of `done`.